# Two images overlapping case in windows phone

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, margin, windows-phone-store

Consider I have a grid in that I place two images A and B. Both are visible all the times as margins are set like that. Here as A is drawn first so B is completely Visible overlapping A partially and hence A is Partially visible. Here my Question comes : I want to alternate this behavior runtime that is , A is completely Visible and B is partially. As I can not redraw B first then A for this to happen. Do we have any property or something like Depth in windows phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Canvas ZIndex (or Panel ZIndex)

Read more about Canvas.ZIndex [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

If you want to set it in code behind, you can do this:

```
someImage.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1); 
someOtherImage.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 2);
```

Comment: +one for ZIndex. Cheers